# Charge on Nitrogen in NCl3

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, oxidation-state, formal-charge

What is the charge on $\ce{N}$ in $\ce{NCl3}$? I want to know if it is positive or negative. I feel it should be positive but I am not sure.

Comment: Judging by the hydrolysis pathway, it is negative.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Can you elaborate?

Comment: NCl3 is said to hydrolyze into NH3 and HClO.

Comment: But if we look at the structure, Cl being more electronegative, should "pull" electrons towards themselves therefore creating a positive charge on Nitrogen.

Comment: Electronegativity is hardly a precise measure of anything.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin But electronegativity plays a dominant role in understanding beginner chemistry?

Comment: Maybe. So what?

Answer (score 2):

First of all charge of atom is not well defined (maybe except AiM). Formal charge of both is zero, but that does not help us to understand chemistry. Above mentioned reaction shows that nitrogen is more negative, and if you do simple QM computation both Mulliken and NBO gives ~-.44 for N and ~+.147 for Cl. If you want to have a bit feeling about it, think that way: both have similar electronegativity but Cl is bigger so it's easier to polarize.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to determine which side of a bond carries a partial positive and which side a partial negative charge, we can attempt to react the substance in question with a nucleophile or electrophile. Nucleophiles will always react with the partially positive component and vice-versa.

We have two nucleophiles that we could use and the reaction of which with $\ce{NCl3}$ are known: $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{H2O}$. The reaction equations are given below:

$$\begin{align}\ce{NCl3 + Cl- + H+ &-> HNCl2 + Cl2}\tag{1}\\
\ce{NCl3 + H2O &-> HNCl2 + HOCl}\tag{2}\end{align}$$

Both show that chlorine carries a positive partial charge.

Answer (score -3):

Charge on an element is given by the oxidation number hence the total charge on the compound is equal to 0 then the charge on nitrogen + chlorine must be equal to 0.

N+3(valency of $\ce{Cl}$) =0

N+3(-1)=0

N-3=0

N=+3

Hence the charge on nitrogen in $\ce{NCl3}$ is +3

Comment: 1st of all atomic charge is not an oxidation state. Even if it would be, then your whole argumentation is based on assumption that Cl is -1. Unfortunately both these elements have nearly equal electronegativity so this assumption is out of blue. Sorry world is not black and white. There are a lot of shades of gray.